# Capybara/Selenium: resize window has no effect and does not work

Tags: selenium, capybara, window-resize

I have a test where I need to first open a page with default window size and then change it to some custom height and width.
To do so I use following code:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1024, 768)
```

But this does not seem to be working. Window size remains the same
Any idea what I am doing wrong? 
I am using chrome driver. And this is how I set up my driver initially (from env setting file):

```
Capybara.configure do |capybara|

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make sure you're using the latest `chromedriver` so it is compatible with the version of Chrome you're using. Currently that would be `chromedriver` 2.33 with Chrome 62.

Secondly, make sure the display you're running on can handle whatever resolution you're resizing to since it's not really well defined what should happen when you specify a size larger than the current system can support

Finally, stop using driver specific methods and just use the Capybara window methods

```
page.current_window.resize_to(1024, 768)
```

Comment: thanks @Thomas Walpole.
Both the driver and display are totally compatible. And in some other tests I can successfully use commands like page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(somewindow). I've tried switching to Capybara window method but also no luck :(

Comment: @MariaK. What versions of Capybara, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, and chrome are you using?

Comment: @MariaK. Also, does the code at https://gist.github.com/twalpole/ec7dafc36f0654931aa8e78b066d56b9 work for you when you run it?

Comment: I'm using capybara 2.14.0, chromedriver 2.32, selenium-webdriver 2.53.4, chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (have been set up like that already when I joined the team). And the code was not working to resize.
So i upgraded to latest selenium-webdriver and capybara and all works like a charm now! Thanks a lot @ThomasWalpole !!! A dummy error from my side, I must admit.